# Calculating Pixel Height of HTML In Template String

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm generating an HTML string in my backend code as follows:

```
const receiptHTML = `<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
<body style="text-align: center;font-weight: bold;font-size: 25px;">
  <h2 style="padding-top: 10px; font-family: Helvetica Neue; font-weight: normal;">
    Order #${item.id}
  </h2>
  <h2 style="background: #f1f1f1; padding: 20px; font-family: Helvetica Neue; font-weight: normal;">
 ...
</body></html>
```

I need to figure out what the height of this HTML is going to be dynamically - is there any way I can do this on the backend without having access to the DOM?

Comment: Throw the body portion into a hidden div and check the height in the page.

Comment: Could you provide a code example?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) library would likely solve your issue. You could also fix the height to a certain value and allow for overflow of the body to occur so it wouldn't impact the formatting.

Comment: This. And also maybe you could use some styling with vh units so the height depends on the height of the viewport?

Comment: the problem is I need to pass the height into a printer SDK to let it know how long the receipt should be - its not a case of formatting.

Comment: @Alk, in that case, you should set a fix hight and overflow area. That'll be your best bet if you're looking for a simple fix.